# preg_replace a specific string with h5 tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to do the following using preg_replace:

```
$text = "
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
***consectetuer adipiscing elit
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor
Aenean massa
"

$regex = "#('\***')(.*?)\n#";
$text = preg_replace($regex1,"<h5>$2</h5>", $text);
```

And than the output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<h5>consectetuer adipiscing elit</h5>
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor
Aenean massa
```

So replace the three * with an opening H5 and than the first line break after the three * replace with the closing H5.

I tried many regex patterns, but with no success. As I'm not familiar with this I hope someone can help me?

Comment: ah, that was it! Works now, thanks for quickly response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex was on the right track.

- The single quotes are uneeded:

  ```
  $regex = "#('\***')(.*?)\n#";
              ↑    ↑
  ```
- And *each* literal `*` needs escaping:

  ```
  $regex = "#(\*\*\*)(.*?)\n#";
  ```

I would also match the `\n` right in the second capture group, or use `\R` for any linebreak. Or perhaps even the `#m` flag and just the line end `$` anchor.

Comment: lovin' those funky ↑ rather than ^'s - much cleaner/precise. I may just follow suit on that.

Comment: (They're the only reason to post answers at all…:)

Comment: Now to sharpen my old ANSI-art skills once again, *ah the good 'ol days of BBS'ing.*

Comment: ↳ As an option you could also use `(\*{3})` instead of `(\*\*\*)` too :) ↑